# What is the time complexity of numpy.linalg.det?

Tags: python, numpy, time-complexity, linear-algebra, determinants

The documentation for [`numpy.linalg.det`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.det.html) states that

> The determinant is computed via LU factorization using the [LAPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK) routine z/[dgetrf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK).

I ran the following run time tests and fit polynomials of degrees 2, 3, and 4 because that covers the least worst options in [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Matrix_algebra). That table also mentions that an LU decomposition approach takes $O(n^3)$ time, but then the theoretical complexity of LU decomposition given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Theoretical_complexity) is $O(n^{2.376})$. Naturally the choice of algorithm matters, but I am not sure what available time complexities I should expect from [`numpy.linalg.det`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.det.html).

```py
from timeit import timeit

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures


sizes = np.arange(1,10001, 100)
times = []

for size in sizes:
    A = np.ones((size, size))
    time = timeit('np.linalg.det(A)', globals={'np':np, 'A':A}, number=1)
    times.append(time)
    print(size, time)

sizes = sizes.reshape(-1,1)
times = np.array(times).reshape(-1,1)

quad_sizes = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2).fit_transform(sizes)
quad_times = LinearRegression().fit(quad_sizes, times).predict(quad_sizes)
cubic_sizes = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3).fit_transform(sizes)
cubic_times = LinearRegression().fit(cubic_sizes, times).predict(cubic_sizes)
quartic_sizes = PolynomialFeatures(degree=4).fit_transform(sizes)
quartic_times = LinearRegression().fit(quartic_sizes, times).predict(quartic_sizes)

plt.scatter(sizes, times, label='Data', color='k', alpha=0.5)
plt.plot(sizes, quad_times, label='Quadratic', color='r')
plt.plot(sizes, cubic_times, label='Cubic', color='g')
plt.plot(sizes, quartic_times, label='Quartic', color='b')
plt.xlabel('Matrix Dimension n')
plt.ylabel('Time (seconds)')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The output of the above is given as the following plot.

[image]

Since none of the available complexities get down to quadratic time, I am unsurprising that visually the quadratic model had the worst fit. Both the cubic and quartic models had excellent visual fit, and unsurprisingly their residuals are closely correlated.

[image]

---

Some related questions exist, but they do not have an answer for this specific implementation.

- [Space complexity of matrix inversion, determinant and adjoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62748765/space-complexity-of-matrix-inversion-determinant-and-adjoint)
- [Time and space complexity of determinant of a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67648438/time-and-space-complexity-of-determinant-of-a-matrix)
- [Experimentally determining computing complexity of matrix determinant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40687798/experimentally-determining-computing-complexity-of-matrix-determinant)

Since this implementation is used by a lot of Python programmers world-wide, it may benefit the understanding of a lot of people if an answer was tracked down.

Comment: The source code is available [here](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/dd/d9a/group__double_g_ecomputational_ga0019443faea08275ca60a734d0593e60.html). I'd recommend posting your question on the computer science stack exchange, as your question is off-topic here.

Comment: @ddejohn Can you tell me why it is off-topic here? I will delete this question and repost it to CS SE shortly.

Comment: Reviewing [*What topics can I ask about here?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), I think my question is on-topic here. I will leave it here unless I get a clarification from moderators. Feel free to vote to close so moderators can see the reason.

Comment: If a dataset fits the cubic model, it should also fit the quartic model (by making the highest coefficient of the quartic model as small as possible). I think your experiment proved the time complexity of `det()` in Numpy is close to O(n^3). Great experiment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**: it is between `O(n^2.81)` and `O(n^3)` regarding the target BLAS implementation.

Indeed, Numpy uses a LU decomposition (in the log space). The actual implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4adc87dff15a247e417d50f10cc4def8e1c17a03/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.c.src#L1148). It indeed uses the `sgetrf`/`dgetrf` primitive of LAPACK. Multiple libraries provides such a libraries. The most famous is the one of NetLib though it is not the fastest. The Intel MKL is an example of library providing a fast implementation. Fast LU decomposition algorithms use tiling methods so to use a matrix multiplication internally. Their do that because the matrix multiplication is one of the most optimized methods linear algebra libraries (for example the MKL, BLIS, and OpenBLAS generally succeed to reach nearly optimal performance on modern processors). More generally, **the complexity of the LU decomposition is the one of the matrix multiplication**.

The complexity of the *naive* squared matrix multiplication is `O(n^3)`. Faster algorithms exists like [*Strassen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) (running in `~O(n^2.81)` time) which is often used for big matrices. The *Coppersmith–Winograd* algorithm achieves a significantly better complexity (`~O(n^2.38)`), but *no linear algebra libraries actually use it* since it is a [**galactic algorithm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_algorithm). Put it shortly, such algorithm is theoretically *asymptotically better* than others but the hidden constant make it *impractical* for any *real-world* usage. For more information about the complexity of the matrix multiplication, please read [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_matrix_multiplication). Thus, **in practice, the complexity of the matrix multiplication is between `O(n^2.81)` and `O(n^3)`** regarding the target BLAS implementation (which is dependent of your platform and your configuration of Numpy).

Comment: How big is the matrix that will use Strassen?

Comment: @IvanaGyro The use of the Strassen algorithm is dependent of the target implementation. AFAIK, mainstream open-source implementations tend not to use it by default since it is not as numerically stable as the naive algorithm. Strassen tends to be faster generally for matrices >1000x1000. The exact threshold is dependent of the target platform, the efficiency of the naive implementation and the one of the Strassen variant. For larger matrices like 8000x8000 a reasonably optimized implementation of Strassen should outperform most highly-optimized BLAS implementations using the naive algorithm.